# Is there a difference between initial-scale=1 and initial-scale=1.0?

Tags: html

I have seen code that is written like this: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`, but I have also seen code that is written like this: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` Is there a difference between initial-scale=1 and initial-scale=1.0?

Answer (score 4):

No. The [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#parsing-algorithm) describes the viewport `<meta>` tag content parsing algorithm non-normatively, but says the following about values:

> If a prefix of property-value can be converted to a number using `strtod`, the value will be that number. The remainder of the string is ignored.

`strtod` is a function from the C standard library. `strtod("1")` is equal to `strtod("1.0")`, which is equal to the number 1, so there's no difference.

Answer (score 1):

`initial-scale` sets the initial zoom factor of the page to the defined value, calculated relative to the ideal viewport. Thus it generates a visual viewport width.
It also sets the layout viewport width to the visual viewport width it just calculated.

As far as I know, there's no difference between `initial-scale=1` and `initial-scale=1.0`.

But I suggest you to use `initial-scale=1.0` to keep the same typewriting with all other possible values (range between 0.1 and 10.0).

Comment: Strictly speaking, all other possible values are not constrained to the step of 0.1, so there is no reason one can't write `initial-scale=1.25` so the typewriting differs anyway